# Android ListView is not selecting rows

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I am trying to use a ListView and I want to select each row to launch different activities, but the method OnItemSelectedItem is not working inside and outside of the OnCreate.

Here is the code.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Activities;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Adapters.MenuAdapter;
import com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Clases.Facultad;
import com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Clases.Menu;
import com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Clases.Pais;
import com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Clases.Universidad;
import com.example.dos_6.app_chef.R;
import com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Util.Util;

import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Util.Constantes.SERVER_GETFACULTAD_ID_UNI;
import static com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Util.Constantes.SERVER_GETMENU;
import static com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Util.Constantes.SERVER_GETMENU_DIA;
import static com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Util.Constantes.SERVER_GETMENU_ID_FACULTAD;
import static com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Util.Constantes.SERVER_GETPAIS;
import static com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Util.Constantes.SERVER_GETUNIVERSIDAD;
import static com.example.dos_6.app_chef.Util.Constantes.SERVER_URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private Intent intent = null;

    private Spinner spinner_universidad = null;
    private Spinner spinner_facultad = null;
    private Spinner spinner_dias = null;

    private ListView lvMenu = null;

    private ListView lvPlatos = null;

    private TextView tv_primer = null;
    private TextView tv_segundo = null;
    private TextView tv_postre = null;
    private TextView tv_bebida = null;

    private Universidad universidad = null;

    private List<Universidad> listaUniversidad = null;
    private List<Facultad> listaFacultad = null;
    private List<Pais> listaPais = null;
    private List<Menu> listaMenu = null;
    private List<Menu> listaPlatos = null;

    private MenuAdapter menuAdapter = null;
    private MenuAdapter platoAdapter = null;

    private WebServiceMenu webServiceMenu = null;

    //TODO nº Semana

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listaUniversidad = new ArrayList<>();
        listaFacultad = new ArrayList<>();
        listaPais = new ArrayList<>();
        listaPlatos = new ArrayList<>();

        spinner_universidad = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.main_spin_lista_uni);
        spinner_dias = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.main_spinner_dias);
        //ListView start
        lvPlatos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_lv_platos);
        lvPlatos.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        String[] ps = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.platos_array);
        Menu m;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < ps.length; i++){
            m = new Menu();
            m.setNombre_plato(ps[i]);
            getListaPlatos().add(m);
        }
        platoAdapter = new MenuAdapter(this, R.layout.menu_item, getListaPlatos());
        lvPlatos.setAdapter(platoAdapter);
        //ListView End
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            WebService webService = new WebService();
            webService.execute();

        listaMenu = new ArrayList<>();

        universidad = new Universidad();
        universidad.setId(0);
        universidad.setNombre(getString(R.string.reg_spinner_pos0_universidad));
        getListaUniversidad().add(0,universidad);
        ArrayAdapter<Universidad> universidadArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Universidad>(this,
                R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getListaUniversidad());
        spinner_universidad.getDropDownHorizontalOffset();
        spinner_universidad.setAdapter(universidadArrayAdapter);
        spinner_universidad.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                getListaFacultad().clear();
                String uni = spinner_universidad.getItemAtPosition(spinner_universidad.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                seleccionarFacultad(uni);
                ArrayAdapter<Facultad> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Facultad>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getListaFacultad());
                spinner_facultad = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.main_spin_lista_fac);
                spinner_facultad.getDropDownHorizontalOffset();
                spinner_facultad.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                spinner_facultad.getOnItemSelectedListener();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> diasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, fillDias());
        spinner_dias.getDropDownHorizontalOffset();
        spinner_dias.setAdapter(diasAdapter);
        spinner_dias.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Facultad facultad = (Facultad) spinner_facultad.getItemAtPosition(spinner_facultad.getSelectedItemPosition());
                    String dia = spinner_dias.getItemAtPosition(spinner_dias.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

                    if(spinner_dias.getSelectedItem().equals(spinner_dias.getItemAtPosition(0))){
                        return;
                    }else {
                        mostrarMenu(dia, String.valueOf(facultad.getId()));
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                return;
            }
        });

    }

    public void seleccionarFacultad(String uni) {
        if (spinner_universidad.getSelectedItem().equals(spinner_universidad.getItemAtPosition(0))) {
            Facultad facultad = new Facultad();
            facultad.setNombre(getString(R.string.reg_spinner_pos0_facultad));
            getListaFacultad().add(facultad);
        } else {
            for(Universidad universidad : getListaUniversidad()){
                if(universidad.getNombre().equals(uni)){
                    Facultad facultad = new Facultad();
                    facultad.setNombre(getString(R.string.reg_spinner_posX_facultad));
                    getListaFacultad().add(0,facultad);
                    WebServiceFacultad  webServiceFacultad = new WebServiceFacultad();
                    webServiceFacultad.execute(String.valueOf(universidad.getId()));

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void mostrarMenu(String dia, String id_facultad){
        WebServiceMenu webServiceMenu = new WebServiceMenu();
        webServiceMenu.execute(dia,id_facultad);

        //menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(this, R.layout.menu_item, getListaMenu());
        //lvMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> fillDias(){
        ArrayList<String> dias = null;

        dias = new ArrayList<>();
        dias.add(getString(R.string.weekday)+" "+Util.numerWeekOfYear());
        //dias.add(getString(R.string.dia_pos0));
        dias.add(getString(R.string.main_bt_lunes));
        dias.add(getString(R.string.main_bt_martes));
        dias.add(getString(R.string.main_bt_miercoles));
        dias.add(getString(R.string.main_bt_jueves));
        dias.add(getString(R.string.main_bt_viernes));
        return dias;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            /*case R.id.main_tv_primer_plato:
                intent = new Intent(this, Platos_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("orden","1");
                intent.putExtra("lista_menu",(Serializable) getListaMenu());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.main_tv_seg_plato:
                intent = new Intent(this, Platos_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("orden","2");
                intent.putExtra("lista_menu",(Serializable) getListaMenu());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.main_tv_postre:
                intent = new Intent(this, Platos_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("orden","3");
                intent.putExtra("lista_menu",(Serializable) getListaMenu());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.main_tv_bebida:
                intent = new Intent(this, Platos_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("orden","4");
                Menu menu = null;
                List<Menu> menuList = new ArrayList<>();
                getListaMenu().clear();
                String[] bebidas = new String[]{"Agua","Refresco","Cerveza"};
                for(int i = 0 ; i < 3;i++){
                    menu = new Menu();
                    menu.setOrden_plato("4");
                    menu.setNombre_plato(bebidas[i]);
                    getListaMenu().add(menu);
                }
                intent.putExtra("lista_menu",(Serializable) getListaMenu());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;*/
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION){
            return;
        }
        Menu menu = getListaPlatos().get(position);
        Intent intent;
        if(menu.getNombre_plato().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.primer_plato))) {
            intent = new Intent(this, Platos_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("orden","1");
            intent.putExtra("lista_menu",(Serializable) getListaMenu());
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(menu.getNombre_plato().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.segundo_plato))){
            intent = new Intent(this, Platos_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("orden","2");
            intent.putExtra("lista_menu",(Serializable) getListaMenu());
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(menu.getNombre_plato().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.postre))){
            intent = new Intent(this, Platos_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("orden","3");
            intent.putExtra("lista_menu",(Serializable) getListaMenu());
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            intent = new Intent(this, Platos_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("orden","4");
            Menu refrescos = null;
            getListaMenu().clear();
            String[] bebidas = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bebidas_array);
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 3;i++){
                refrescos = new Menu();
                refrescos.setOrden_plato("4");
                refrescos.setNombre_plato(bebidas[i]);
                getListaMenu().add(refrescos);
            }
            intent.putExtra("lista_menu",(Serializable) getListaMenu());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, menu.getNombre_plato(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private class WebService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Universidad[] universidadArray=null;

            try{
                universidadArray = restTemplate.getForObject(SERVER_URL + SERVER_GETUNIVERSIDAD, Universidad[].class);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }

            for(Universidad universidad : universidadArray){
                getListaUniversidad().add(universidad);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.mensaje_cargando);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            if (dialog != null)
                dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
         }
    }

    private class WebServicePais extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Pais[] paisArray = restTemplate.getForObject(SERVER_URL+SERVER_GETPAIS, Pais[].class);
            getListaPais().addAll(Arrays.asList(paisArray));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //spinner_universidad.setAdapter(null);

            /*dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.mensaje_cargando);
            dialog.show();*/
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            if (dialog != null)
                dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

    private class WebServiceFacultad extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            int id_uni = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Facultad[] facultadArray = restTemplate.getForObject(SERVER_URL + SERVER_GETFACULTAD_ID_UNI+id_uni, Facultad[].class);
            getListaFacultad().addAll(Arrays.asList(facultadArray));
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class WebServiceMenu extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Menu[] menu = restTemplate.getForObject(SERVER_URL+SERVER_GETMENU+SERVER_GETMENU_DIA+params[0]
                    +SERVER_GETMENU_ID_FACULTAD+Integer.parseInt(params[1]), Menu[].class);
            getListaMenu().addAll(Arrays.asList(menu));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            getListaMenu().clear();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.mensaje_cargando);
            dialog.show();
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (dialog != null)
                dialog.dismiss();

            //menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

       if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public List<Universidad> getListaUniversidad() {
        return listaUniversidad;
    }

    public void setListaUniversidad(List<Universidad> listaUniversidad) {
        this.listaUniversidad = listaUniversidad;
    }

    public List<Pais> getListaPais() {
        return listaPais;
    }

    public void setListaPais(List<Pais> listaPais) {
        this.listaPais = listaPais;
    }

    public List<Facultad> getListaFacultad() {
        return listaFacultad;
    }

    public void setListaFacultad(List<Facultad> listaFacultad) {
        this.listaFacultad = listaFacultad;
    }

    public List<Menu> getListaMenu() {
        return listaMenu;
    }

    public void setListaMenu(List<Menu> listaMenu) {
        this.listaMenu = listaMenu;
    }

    public List<Menu> getListaPlatos() {
        return listaPlatos;
    }

    public void setListaPlatos(List<Menu> listaPlatos) {
        this.listaPlatos = listaPlatos;
    }
}
```

And each row is using this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_imv"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Switch" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menuitem_tv_nombre_plato"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: there  is a stacktrace? if so, put it here

Answer (score 0):

use click inside adapter. something like cause i don't know your adapter class i paste from my codes.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card_list, null);
      }



  convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
  });

  convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

      return true;
    }
  });



      return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR my gut response would be overlapping Listeners (I count 6 separate Listener calls in one Activity).  Put Log.e events in each listener, click what you want to click and see what Log.e fires.  You'll know what Listener is being called (in other words, which Listener is eating up you click events).

If none are fired that you most likely haven't implemented your Listener correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you create custom adapter.

Try below link :-

http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial